# java - Editor does not contain a main type

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse error: “Editor does not contain a main type”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050066/eclipse-error-editor-does-not-contain-a-main-type)

I am currently coding a server socket application where you can connect to several clients via a thread pool.

But when I want to compile the main I get:

[image]

Why do I get that? I still have a main in my mainServer.java

I appreciate your answer!!!

Comment: The Eclipse view of the file can become out of sync with the file itself. Try restarting and run again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your Launch Configuration is pointed to ServerMain, and if it isn't, make sure you do `Run As > Java Application`.

Otherwise you could try a `Project > Clean`

Also some more questions that deals with this that could be helpful, 
[Eclipse error: "Editor does not contain a main type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050066/eclipse-error-editor-does-not-contain-a-main-type?rq=1)
[Editor does not contain a main type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113729/editor-does-not-contain-a-main-type?rq=1)

Answer (score 4):

Please make sure your project source (src) folder is on the build path. If not, the main() method may not be included in your project. You can follow the below steps to verify your source path settings:

- Right click on your project from `Package Explorer`.
- Select `Properties (ALT + Enter)`
- Go to `Java Build Path Click` on `Source` tab &  check
  whether the source folder is on the build path

Once the verification is completed, you may please close your project & reopen it. Then, you should be able to right click on a class file with a main method (`ServerMain.java in your case`) and run it.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your main class (has to be static to my understanding) in the properties of the project.

Make sure it points to the right location.

http://protegewiki.stanford.edu/images/2/24/Protege41InEclipseRunnableMainTab.png

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue some times, i use workaround for this.
go to package explorer and then go to desired class(class under .java file), right click and run as java application

Comment: This says `Selection does not contain a main type`