# Running JUnit on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am trying to run the below code in Eclipse.

It's giving me an error "*Editor does not contain a main type*" but it does as you can see `public static void main(String args[])`.

Anyone know how to run this or why it does not recognize the main method?

```
package org.axiondb.functional;

import junit.framework.Test;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;

/**
 * @version $Revision: 1.26 $ $Date: 2005/05/03 18:02:23 $
 * @author Rodney Waldhoff
 * @author Chuck Burdick
 */
public class TestAll extends TestCase {

    public TestAll(String testName) {
        super(testName);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] testCaseName = { TestAll.class.getName() };
        junit.textui.TestRunner.main(testCaseName);
    }

    public static Test suite() {
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
        suite.addTest(TestDatatypes.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestDDL.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestDQL.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestDQLMisc.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestDQLDisk.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestDQLWithArrayIndex.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestDQLDiskWithArrayIndex.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestDQLWithBTreeIndex.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestDQLDiskWithBTreeIndex.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestDML.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestDMLMisc.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestDMLDisk.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestDMLWithArrayIndex.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestDMLDiskWithArrayIndex.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestDMLWithBTreeIndex.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestDMLDiskWithBTreeIndex.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestMemoryClob.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestDiskClob.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestMemoryBlob.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestDiskBlob.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestThreadedSelect.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestIndexedJoin.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestBugs.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestAxionBTreeDelete.suite());        
        suite.addTest(TestSpecials.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestFunctions.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestThreadedDML.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestTransactions.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestTransactionsDisk.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestConstraints.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestBooleanLiterals.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestTransactionalLobs.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestTransactionalLobsDisk.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestMetaData.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestMetaDataDisk.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestDatabaseLock.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestIndexSpecials.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestForElmar.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestPrepareStatement.suite());
        suite.addTest(TestGroupByAndOrderBy.suite());

        suite.addTest(TestBinaryStream.suite());
        return suite;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `Editor` in `Editor does not contain a main type`

Comment: did you try Run As... > JUnit Test ?

Comment: @Marco it says no JUNIT tests found when i run as Junit test

Comment: You are not actually telling Eclipse to run this class.  You are telling it to run a class called `Editor`, which you've also written.  Right-click on this class and tell it to run.

Comment: @freak i dont know. thats what the error message pop up. "Editor does not contain a main type" it doesnt say anything else

Comment: Did you import the JUnit 3.x or the JUnit 4 library to your project?

Comment: See another similar thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050066/eclipse-error-editor-does-not-contain-a-main-type
Though it isn't exact duplicate but exactly same issue under different scenario. Try the solutions discussed in this thread.

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot now it says "Selection does not contain main type"

Comment: can you trim the class a bit? ie. remove 99% of the suite.addTest lines

Comment: @MarcoForberg yes i have JUNIT 4.11 imported

Comment: @ealon just wondering since your code looks like a JUnit 3 TestCase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reopening the file, then run the test.
Otherwise, restart Eclipse. please let me know if this solves the problem! or else give me more details and I'll try and help.