# Java text file input

Tags: java, input

i am currently doing a small task in java which i am very new to so please excuse any silly mistakes i have made. Basically i am trying to take 2 values from a text document, import them into my java document and then multiply them together. These 2 numbers are meant to represent the hourly pay and amount of hours worked, then the output is the total amount the member of staff has earned. This what i have so far ...

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;  

public class WorkProject 
{ 

    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("staffnumbers.txt"));

    double Hours;
    double Pay;

    Hours = inFile.nextDouble();
    Pay = inFile.nextDouble();
    double earned = Length * Width;

            System.out.println(earned);
    }
```

What i have so far is basically me trying to get the .txt document into my java file. I'm not sure if this is right and then i'm not sure where to go to get the values to multiply and have it outputted. I understand what i have so far is probably just the very start of what i need but any help will be massively appreciated as i am keen to learn. Thanks so much .... Hannah

Comment: `I'm not sure if this is right`  well, you can check, simply write `System.out.println(earned)` to see if you've done it right.

Comment: You've already gotten the values to multiply. They are stored in the variables called Hours and Pay. The last line though, is not correct. You need to declare a double called `Amount` and set it equal to `Hours * Pay`.

Comment: By the way, there are no spaces allowed in variable names, and usually variables are named using camelCase. Camel case means every variable starts with a lower case letter and if it has more than one word, from the 2nd word and onward you start with a capital letter. Example: if you wanted a variable to store the amount earned, the name of the variable would be `amountEarned`. Best of luck to you learning how to program. ;)

Comment: you can just type double earned = Hours * Pay, you didn´t declare Length and Width.

Comment: Thank you all so much for you replies, i have changed the end to..
      double earned = Pay * Hours;
      System.out.println(earned);
Should this give me output because now i have an error after the ''double pay;'' saying it's expecting a {

Comment: @HannahLivestrong Edit your post to contain your updated code. Include the whole file... it sounds like you are just missing a bracket.

Comment: i've updated the code to what i have now on my original post

Comment: @HannahLivestrong You need to put the code inside a `main` method, which basically acts as a starting point for the execution. To be honest, I would recommend starting with some simpler tutorials. I'll be generous though and show you how to do it in my answer.

Comment: Ahh i new about that i feel stupid now guess i just need to take my time more, i'll go over some tutorials yes. However i am getting an error now with that code saying "editor does not contain main type"
You've been more than a great help so i wont be offended if i'm asking to many questions and you don't reply lol!

Comment: @HannahLivestrong I don't know off the top of my head what the problem is...but this was one of the first results when I googled the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050066/eclipse-error-editor-does-not-contain-a-main-type. Does that help at all?

Comment: I made a new document and re-saved and it somewhere different and it was fine, i read somewhere it was due to the location i'd saved it and it worked... last question i promise as this is all i'm missing now... my code can't find my .txt file, i'm currently looking on google for some tutorials but nothing has worked of yet

Comment: @HannahLivestrong If you are just using the command line to compile/run your code, you should be able to just put the file in the same directory as your java code.

Comment: I made it on notepad++ and saved it into exactly where my java code is saved in eclipse?

Comment: @HannahLivestrong Put the full file path as the filename. For example, if the file was in my `C:` directory, then the full path would be `C:\staffnumbers.txt` but since the \ symbol is an escape character, you have to put it twice every time you see it. So you get `C:\\staffnumbers.txt` This is also in my answer below.

Comment: So I would just move the staffnumbers.txt file to your C: directory so it will work, then once you get it working you can move it around and figure it out from there.

Comment: I have it working, i can't thank you enough you've been great! Believe me it's very much appreciated and i feel I've learned a lot... thanks again.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what `Amount earned` is. So my guess is you need to change the last line to

```
double amountEarned = Hours * Pay; //this multiplies the values
System.out.println(amountEarned);  //this outputs the value to the console
```

EDIT:
Putting code inside a `main` method:

```
public class WorkProject {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

      Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:\\staffnumbers.txt"));

      double Hours;
      double Pay;

      Hours = inFile.nextDouble();
      Pay = inFile.nextDouble();
      double amountEarned = Hours * Pay;

      System.out.println(amountEarned);
    }
}
```

Comment: Amount earned is meant to be amountEarned yes sorry, does the first bit look correct for reading from a text file?

Comment: @HannahLivestrong Yes it is correct, although you will have to handle a possible FileNotFoundException...

Comment: Are you sure? It looks like the Javadoc says that `Scanner` takes `File` as a parameter, not `FileReader`...

Comment: @CoderOfHonor `FileReader` is a subclass of `Reader`, which `Scanner` can also take as a constructor parameter. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Huh, am I reading this wrong? It looks like http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html says that it takes a `Readable`. Does FileReader implement Readable?

Comment: @CoderOfHonor Ah sorry you are right, `Reader` implements `Readable` though, so it is ok.

Comment: @jlars62 Ok, makes sense. So where can I find what each class implements? I've been scanning the javadocs for a section that details it, but I can't find one.

Comment: @CoderOfHonor At the top of the javadocs it states what the class implements and any known direct subclasses. So on this page, we see that Reader implements Readable and Closeable, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html. You can also see that InputStreamReader is a subclass, and if you click on it, you will see that FileReader is a subclass of InputStreamReader. And on the FileReader page, you can see the chain of of super classes that go back to it extending an object.

Comment: @jlars62 Thanks! I see it now. I'm too used to relying on eclipse to do that sort of stuff for me. I should probably start using the javadocs more often. :]

Comment: @CoderOfHonor Well to be honest I knew it worked because I threw the code into my IDE (Intellij) and it didn't complain lol. Then looking at the javadocs I saw why...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40135/discussion-between-coderofhonor-and-jlars62)

Comment: I am struggling to get this to be error free is there anyway to talk one on one to you guys as i'm very keen to learn and you both seem knowledgeable on the subject lol!

Answer (score 0):

```
// Matt Stillwell
// April 12th 2016
// File must be placed in root of the project folder for this example 

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Input
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        // declarations
        Scanner ifsInput;
        String sFile;

        // initializations
        ifsInput = null;
        sFile = "";

        // attempts to create scanner for file
        try
        {
            ifsInput = new Scanner(new File("document.txt"));
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File Doesnt Exist");
            return;
        }

        // goes line by line and concatenates the elements of the file into a string
        while(ifsInput.hasNextLine())
            sFile = sFile + ifsInput.nextLine() + "\n";     

        // prints to console
        System.out.println(sFile);

    }
}
```