# Editor does not contain a main type in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I downloaded `eclipse-jee-kepler-SR1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz`. This eclipse is built-in with java and my Lubuntu is 64-bit. Whenever I compile and run a simple code in java like this one below:

```
public class Sample{

   public static void main(String[] args){
       System.out.println("YOLO");
   }
}
```

I always get an `Editor does not contain a main type`.
I put the file in a project folder called `Sample`. This eclipse should compile java code because its an IDE distribution specialized for java.

How can i resolve this error?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's my project structure:
[image]

Comment: Did you try cleaning and building your project?. Show us your project structure from eclipse.

Comment: Put screen shot of **marks** window in your question. Because you have to consider about exclamation mark in view.

Comment: thank you to all who replied. It suddenly worked. I don't know how but I restarted, cleaned and created new project and created file inside src folder. Thanks!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hrS_uvswsnk   refer this link for error resolvement .

Answer (score 70):

Problem is that your folder is not identified as a Source folder.

1. Right click on the project folder -> Properties
2. Choose 'Java Build Path'
3. Click on 'Sources' tab on top
4. Click on 'Add Folder' on the right panel
5. Select your folders and apply

Comment: This answer helped me realize that I had created my project as new General Project instead of new Java Project.

Comment: I tried this, but getting same error. I also clean and build the solution.

Comment: I have moved the code to src folder and it worked.

Comment: The only thing that helped is to move the .java file to src folder.

Comment: Also if all these does not help , try restarting your IDE. In my case it helped me.

Answer (score 16):

I just had this exact same problem. This will sound crazy but if someone sees this try this before drastic measures. delete method signature:

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

(Not the body of your main just method declaration)

Save your project then re-write the method's header back onto its respective body. Save again and re-run. That worked for me but if it doesn't work try again but clean project right before re-running.

I don't know how this fixed it but it did. Worth a shot before recreating your whole project right?

Comment: This also seemed to have solved my imports not showing as an auto-import option issue... odd

Comment: This solved My problem too .. I just went a step ahead, added a space and then removed it. Saved and ran.

Answer (score 14):

Right click your project > Run As > Run Configuration... > Java Application (in left side panel) - double click on it. That will create new configuration. click on search button under Main Class section and select your main class from it.

Comment: It helped me alot.  But during the course of fixing it i faced challange of selecting main Class. Inbuilt search didn't work properly. So I entered main class location in Main.class section in Run configuration page.

Answer (score 14):

I suspect the problem is that Sample.java should be in a package inside the src folder.

I guess that eclipse will not automatically look outside of there.

Comment: If you are not in a place to change the package, try marking the current package under sources. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50087008/3604656

Answer (score 6):

First look for  the main method is there or not.If it is there, do restart your eclipse and right click on the page which having main method, Go to run as Java application.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you do Run As > Java Application.

If not you could try a Project > Clean

Some more questions that deals with this that could be helpful, 
[Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050066/eclipse-error-editor-does-not-contain-a-main-type)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Create a source folder under Java Resources
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me, classpath entry in `.classpath` file isn't pointing to the right location. After modifying it to `<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>` fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the source code file should go within the src/default package even if you haven't provided any package name. For some reason, the source file might be outside src folder. Create within the scr folder it will work!

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Sample.java file and delete it. Now go to File -> New -> Class   , enter name of program (i.e. hello) , click on finish . It will create file hello.java. Enter source code of program and finallly press ctrl + F11

[image: click here to see screenshot1]

[image: click here to see screenshot2]

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project, select New -> Source Folder

Enter src as Folder name, then click finish.

Eclipse will then recognize the src folder as containing Java code, and you should be able to set up a run configuration

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I had accidentally deleted the **.classpath and .project** file in my workspace. Luckily it was in Recycle bin, as soon as it was restored, there were no issues.

Answer (score -6):

Just change "String[] args" to "String args[]".