# "Selection does not contain a main type" what to do

Tags: java, eclipse

[I am not able to execute my program what to do whenever i run using run as application it shows "selection does not contain main type"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JupAK.jpg)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117713/editor-does-not-contain-a-main-type-in-eclipse

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).